# Show that $(R, +, 0)$ is generated by the closed interval $X = [0, 1]$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

Show that $(R,+, 0)$ is generated by the closed interval $X = [0, 1]$

Show that $(Q,+,0)$ is generated by the set $X=\{(1/n)) :n≥1\}$

I can't find anything to help me with these questions.

Comment: For any $x \in \Bbb R$ there is some $m \in \Bbb N$ such that $|\frac{x}{m}| \le 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(\Bbb R,+,0)$ is generated by any interval $(u,v)$ with $u<v$.

Indeed, with $r:=v-u>0$, we find $x\in\langle (u,v)\rangle$ for $|x|<r$ simply because $x=\frac{u+v+x}2-\frac{u+v-x}2$ where $u=\frac{u+v-r}2<\frac{u+v\pm x}2<\frac{u+r+v}2=v$.
Now for arbitrary $x\in\Bbb R$, let $n=\lfloor \frac{|x|}r\rfloor$. Then $y:=\frac1n x\in(-r,r)\subset \langle (u,v)\rangle$, and hence $x=\underbrace{y+\cdots +y}_n\in \langle (u,v)\rangle$.